# Dynamically filter table to another sheet in an online excel file

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, xlsx

I have an Excel file which will be kept in SharePoint. It runs a query every 5 minutes to get data from another Excel file in which data comes regularly through power automate. This is what the table looks like:

[image]

I want to lock this sheet and get filtered data dynamically in another sheet in the same Excel file. I am trying to get all entries where "Approval Status" is "Approved".

Can we do this without using macros? I want to keep the .xlsx extension of the file.

Comment: Does your version of Excel support the FILTER function?

Comment: I have Excel 2016, it's not present for my version

Answer (score 0):

Can you use FILTER?
`=FILTER(Table1,Table1[Approval Status]="Approved")`

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have Excel 2016, FILTER isn't supported in my version :(